# Regex or IndexOf?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a long string "AB100123485;AB10064279293-IP-1-KNPO;AB473898487-MM41". I have to extract integer value after "IP-"  i.e 1 (only) what is the most efficient way ? I am using c#

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'most-efficient' way depends on how consistent your string is in terms of length and appearance. You can surely do this with a regular expression as a quick solution if you just want to get the digit directly following IP-.

You can utilize the RegularExpressions API, passing in your regular expression and input string.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_System_String_

This pattern should get you started `IP-[0-9]`; refine it more to your use case as needed.

For example:

```
Match matched = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match(
    "AB100123485;AB10064279293-IP-1-KNPO;AB473898487-MM41", 
    "IP-[0-9]"
);
```